# sendmail and pacemaker require different /etc/hosts

Tags: sendmail, fail2ban, pacemaker, hosts

Trying to make run sendmail (required by fail2ban, or it takes forever to start-stop-restart it) and pacemaker on one machine.

Sendmail wants machine's hostname resolved as 127.0.0.1, pacemaker - as 192.168.100.1, otherwise they both don't work correctly. Can't figure out, how to achieve this in /etc/hosts, or it is simpler to use postfix? or remove mail notifications in fail2ban?

Comment: `sendmail` should not require this. Is the FQDN defined the same in both `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your "sendmail.mc" and add:

```
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
```

But be sure that you have all the hostnames you need configured in the file "local-host-names".